# Java - How to check if a list is in list of lists

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I have a list and list of lists.

How do I check if `data` is in `sheet` list and remove it from `data` list? I tried using containsAll() but it's not removing the same list. I might be doing something wrong.

```
import java.util.*;

public class RemoveSameListData {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<List<Object>> sheet = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Object> data = new ArrayList<>();
        data.add("a");
        data.add("a");
        data.add("b");
       
        List<Object> data2 = new ArrayList<>();
        data2.add("c");
        data2.add("b");
        data2.add("bv");

        List<Object> data3 = new ArrayList<>();
        data3.add("s");
        data3.add("as");
        data3.add("e");
        
        sheet.add(data);
        sheet.add(data2);
        sheet.add(data3); //here sheet is [[a, a, b], [c, b, bv], [s, as, e]]


        for (List<Object> sameData : sheet) {
           if(data.containsAll(sameData)) {
              data.remove(sameData);
           }
        }
        System.out.println(data);
    }
}
```

Basically, i want to be able to remove list from `data` that's available in `sheet`.

Any input is always appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Just  `sheet.remove(data)` should work, no need to loop

Comment: `Object` compare reference by default(not value). are you using same object or different one, in different arrays?

Comment: @LeiYang they should be two different objects if not mistaken. thanks for the tip. let me see if i can try converting it to string or such.

Comment: @Lino tried that. same it seems

Comment: @tiredqa_18 please paste a short snippet that can directly copy and compile. for example, don't use variables `a`, `b` defined somewhere else.

Comment: added snippet so easy to copy and compile @LeiYang

Answer (score 1):

like @[Lei Yang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1518100/lei-yang) pointed out in his comment (credits to him!), the equality of list's is checked by equality of the objects.
Thus this succeeds:

```
List<List<Object>> sheet = new ArrayList<>(List.of(List.of("a", "a", "b"), List.of("c", "b", "bv"), List.of("s", "as", "e")));
List<Object> data = List.of("a", "a", "b");
assertTrue(sheet.remove(data));
```

Comment: thanks Rainer! I think I get it now. Was trying to wrap my head around it. Big thanks to 
@LeiYang too for pointing it out!

Comment: @tiredqa_18 Please upvote Lei's answer if not already done :-)